# Given a matrix $A$ and its transformation $B$ to a orthogonal basis $X$, can I find the basis $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given a matrix in a certain basis (say, canonical) and the matrix in another (orthogonal) basis $X$, is there a way to find out the basis $X$ itself?

$$A = X^T B X$$

where the matrices $A$ and $B$ are known, $X$ is unknown.

I tried to do some algebraic manipulations but I cannot keep $X$ in only one side of the equation.

[edit] Responding comments:

- The matrices $A$ and $B$ are not scalar.
- A computational approximate is sufficient.
- Even if the solution is non-unique, I need to find some $X$ such that the above relation is valid.

Comment: What if $A = B$ is scalar matrix?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get an answer on paper/in closed form, or would a computer/approximate approach be sufficient?

Comment: Also, as the other comment alludes to, the solution $X$ will be non-unique, with the extent of non-uniqueness depending on the properties of $A$ (or equivalently those of $B$)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, then a simple approach is to simply diagonalize both $A$ and $B$ (via a spectral decomposition) and use the eigenbases to obtain $X$.

Comment: For  $A=B=I,$ there are many matrices with the property $X^TX=I.$

Comment: @mihaild please see the edit.

Comment: @BenGrossmann please see the edit.

Comment: It might be helpful to frame the problem as follows: you're looking for an orthogonal matrix $X$ that satisfies the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) $BX - XA = 0$.

Comment: One option that seems promising is the [Manopt toolbox](https://www.manopt.org/), which you can use to find an orthogonal matrix of minimal distance from the solution space to $BX - XA = 0$.

Comment: You may be able to construct this matrix column by column using Bartels-Stewart (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm) or some other algorithm to solve Sylvester equations. However, the original problem only makes sense if $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, so their Schur components will have the same diagonals and the linear systems in the algorithm will have non-unique solutions and you have to make some arbitrary choices to get a solution. If $A$ and $B$ are normal, then you can find a solution directly using their orthogonal diagonalizing transformations.

Comment: The point of mihaild and Ryszard Szwarc's comments is because algebraic manipulation of the full matrices does not destinguish between scalar and non-scalar matrices, and the scalar case has infinitely many solutions, this problem cannot be solved by just algebra on the full matrices. You will have to break open $A, B, X$ and start playing with their innards to solve it, as Ben Grossmann and whpowell96 are discussing. That $A$ and $B$ are not scalar matrices (no one was actually suggesting they were) does not make any difference in this.